# Estimating binary response variable that is the result of thresholding on binomially distributed data in R?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, binary-data

Suppose that I have binomial data generated as $V \sim Bin(N,p)$ and a thresholding rule such that for $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$,

$$
Y_i=\begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if} \ \  V_i > m  \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

I am wondering how I can estimate $Y_i$ from such a process in using `glm` in `R`. My mock simulation below has $N=1000$, $p=0.05$, and $m=2$:

```
V <- rbinom(n=1000,size=50,p=0.05)
X <- 1*(V > 2)
```

To estimate,

```
mod <- glm(X ~ V, family=binomial())
mod$fitted
```

but it gives errors and warnings and it is apparent `mod$fitted` is quite off. What is the correct way for estimating the mock data I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you know as you start estimating.
Clearly, sequences `X` and `V` and that `V` is binomial. If you also know
the number of binomial trials $n = 50,$ it's easier.

I don't see what's wrong with your code. However, even though $N = 1000$ observations isn't much to go on, it seems reasonable to get
some information directly from `X` and `V`.

*If $n$ is unknown.* [The absolute value for `p` is to protect against
the rare case where `var(V) > mean(V)`; there must be a better way.
If you know `p` is large, then maybe use `n = max(V)`. MMEs are unstable if `p` is small; see note at end.]

```
set.seed(123)
V = rbinom(1000, 50, 0.05)
X = 1*(V > 2)
m = min(V[X==1])-1;  m
[1] 2
p = abs(1 - var(V)/mean(V)); p
[1] 0.06922059
n = round(mean(V)/p); n
[1] 36
```

*If $n = 50$ is known:*

```
set.seed(123)
V = rbinom(1000, 50, 0.05)
X = 1*(V > 2)
m = min(V[X==1])-1;  m
[1] 2
p = mean(V)/50;  p
[1] 0.04968
```

If I have totally misunderstood what you are trying to do, please leave
a Comment.

Note: [This paper](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Eboos/library/mimeo.archive/ISMS__1539.pdf) and its references may be relevant if Binomial $n$ is unknown.